# Basic Python, checking if a certain interger is in a larger number

Tags: python

Im working on a kind of mastermind game for my first computer science class. I was wondering how to check if numbers match. For ex. a random generated number could be 1637 and you enter 4526 and i ask how to check the number 6 is in the rnd number.

edit: I should have been more precise in the explanation. This was my "task"

Generate a random four digit number. The player has to keep inputting four digit numbers until they guess the randomly generated number. After each unsuccessful try it should say how many numbers they got correct.

Comment: It is important to note that *numbers don't contain other numbers*. Their representations may involve similar digits. You can either do the math on the numbers to determine this, or more simply, don't use *numbers*, i.e. `int` or `float` objects, and rather, use a *collection of digits*, maybe a `str`, or maybe a `list` of `int` objects, and then you can directly check `if some_int in my_list_of_ints`

Comment: As simple as `str(num1) in str(num2)`

Comment: Is it not just checking equality like `if num_generated == 6:`?

Comment: The integer `6` is not in the integer `1637`; the *string* `"6"` is in the *string* `"1637"` , or the integer `6` is in the *list* `[1, 6, 3, 7]`.

Comment: I actually think this is a common stumbling point for people starting out programming. The fact that higher-level languages just *provide* data types that work as you'd hope kind of makes people unaware of what is really going on. I think the downvotes are a bit unfair, especially to a new contributor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do string comparisons, an example is shown below:

```
import random
for x in range(10):
  myNum = random.randint(1,101)
  if "5" in str(myNum):
      print("5 is in " + str(myNum))
  else:
      print("5 not in "+ str(myNum))
```

obviously, 5 could be any number you'd like, if however you want to check if 4564 and 2126 contain the same numbers here's what you could do.

```
num1list = []
num2list = []
num1 = "4564"
num2 = "2126"
for num in num1:
    num1list.append(num)
for num in num2:
    num2list.append(num)
#Now we have lists with individual digits
# traverse in the 1st list
for element in num1list:
    if element in num2list:
        print(element+" is present in both lists")
```

this would return the following:
6 is present in both lists

an example output is shown below from the first section of code.

5 not in 97

5 not in 8

5 not in 93

5 not in 6

5 is in 25

5 not in 20

5 not in 97

5 not in 1

5 not in 81

5 not in 100

Answer (score 0):

If im reading this right, to do this the best way would be to keep 4526 as a string, and turn your rand var into a string and use .split and then use 2 nested for loops to check. Something That would be easier would be to have generate 4 random numbers between 0 and 9 then have each number enter separately and compare them as you go. If you need any more help just ask.

Comment: You can also check if a value is in a string by using `in`

Comment: @GameMaster I honestly did not know that was a thing. Thanks. Ya learn something new every day.

Comment: You’re welcome. It also works with arrays/lists.